# Use sed to append specific lines in file to end of another file

Tags: linux, bash, sed

file foo has

```
one 
two
```

file bar has

```
two
three
four
five
```

I would like to append lines 2-3 of bar to the end of foo so that foo looks like

```
one 
two
three
four
```

How would I do this? I know insert would be `sed -n '2,3p' bar > foo`, so I tried `sed -n '2,3p' bar >> foo` but that didn't work; I'm doing everything within an ssh connection, which hangs

EDIT:

This isn't much of a solution, but previously this was running within a bash command alongside another sed call. I moved it to a separate command, and that worked.

Comment: please edit question to show your current results. I'm pretty sure your `sed .. >> foo` should work. If your files were created in Windows-land and now being processed on *nix. Then use `dos2unix foo bar` and retry your `sed`. Good luck.

Comment: What didn't work about this? Please verify the contents of `foo` and `bar`. You may have inadvertently overwritten one of the files since you used `bar > foo` in one of your examples.

Answer (score 3):

Your second attempt looks correct to me, assuming you didn't first overwrite `foo` with your first attempt. That is, from the initial state described, running:

```
sed -n '2,3p' bar >>foo
```

Should append lines 2 and 3 of `bar` to `foo`.

In general, it is often a good idea to make `sed` quit immediately after you know you're done with it, e.g., by adding the `q` command for the following line:

```
    sed -n '2,3p;4q' bar >>foo
```

Now if `bar` is, say, 10 million lines long, it will still quit on line 4 instead of line 10,000,000. (Test something like `seq 1 10000000 | sed …` to see the difference.) Naturally this doesn't matter for your example of four lines in the file.

Answer (score 1):

Using awk:

```
awk 'NR==2||NR==3' file2 >> file1
```

Comment: If the sed command he's using doesn't work, neither will that.  The problem likely lies elsewhere.

Comment: True I agree and that's the reason I suggested an alternate approach.